# Join two table in the single query. Need query to execute my php code

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 table called **result** and **subject**

[image: result table]

[image: subject table]

and i want to show data like this

[image: click here]

I have the following code :

```
$result_hallticket= "13d01a0589";
$subject_department= "Civil";
```

if i search with any hallticket and department, the subject name and max marks shows every time with  the select statement

```
select * 
from subject 
where subject_department='$subject_department' 
  AND subject_semester="1-1";
```

So i want all subject name should come and internal and external marks come from result database with the matching of hallticket and semester. If the matching found then show the number

```
subject_name=result_subject
```

if not found any result then show only 0 marks in both internal and external marks.

i need a single query to show these all.

What i actually need:
I need a table with 4 column (Subject Name, Max Marks, Internal Marks, External Marks)

The Subject Name and Max Marks come from **subject** table and internal marks and external marks will come from **result** table.

The Subject Name and Max Marks will depends upon department and semester. And the Internal marks and external marks will depends upon hallticket, semester and subject.

Comment: Most people here want sample data as formatted text. not images. (And I can't read that tiny image text.)

Comment: use right click option and select open image in new tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a left join:

```
select 
  s.subject_name "SUBJECT NAME", 
  s.subject_maxmarks "MAX MARKS",
  ifnull(r.result_internalmarks, 0) "INTERNAL MARKS",
  ifnull(r.result_externalmarks, 0) "EXTERNAL MARKS"
from subject s left join results r
on r.result_subject = s.subject_name
where 
  s.subject_department='$subject_department' 
  and
  s.subject_semester="1-1";
```

Comment: great. but what about the hallticket. There are many hall ticket but the department and subject is same. So the result must show all subject name and max marks for any hall ticket. As hall ticket change, Only the marks should change. And the subject is change only if the department and semester is different.

Comment: If you want to search for a certain hallticket just add it to the where part: `...and r.result_hallticket = '$result_hallticket'`. This column exists only in the results table, right, so you can filter but not join on it.

Comment: then how i can do that.

Comment: you are not understanding my point. i dont want the filter. using the filter for hallticket   only only that subject should come which is having hallticket. I need all subject for any hallticket.

Comment: I don't see a hallticket column in the subjects table. So the join is placed on subject only. I think you should post more data to clarify what you need.

Comment: Can u share me your social. So i can talk on that. MSG me

Comment: I don't do any other communication outside of SO. If you want your problem solved you must clarify and/or post more data and expected results hopefully in text format and not images.

Comment: Updated please check

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you want to display the marks if there is a corresponding record in the table, or zero if there is not.

You might look at `LEFT OUTER JOIN` (and understand the difference between it and `INNER JOIN`s), and then use `IFNULL()` to coalesce the null to zero.

Comment: Can you share the query. It will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Hope This Help

```
    SELECT result.result_internalmarks,result.result_externalmarks
    FROM result INNER JOIN subject ON
    result.result_subject = subject.subject_name WHERE
    result.result_hallticket = '$result_hallticket' AND 
    result.result_department = '$subject_department'
```

Comment: I don't think that's going to replace NULLs with zero, it'll just exclude them.